# Why doesn't my form get posted in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, submit

I am using a simple form and submitting my textbox values to database,

```
<body>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
$des="Insert into enquiry(Companyname,Name,Phno,Email,Address,Comments) values 
  ('".$_POST[txtcompname]."','".$_POST[txtname]."','".$_POST[txtphno]."',
'".$_POST[txtemail]."','".$_POST[txtaddress]."','".$_POST[txtcomments]."')";
$res1=mysql_query($des);

?>

<div align="left">
<form action="" method="post">
```

But it doesn't seem to get submitted? Any suggestion

When i use `print_r($_POST);` i get

```
Array ( [txtcompname] => xv [txtname] => xcv [txtphno] => xcvx [txtemail] => xcv [txtaddresss] => xcv [txtcomments] => xcvxcv [submit] => submit )
```

and i get this error now,

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Address,Comments) 
values ('zdc','sadcv','zdsv', 'sdcv','sdvcsdv','sdcv')' at line 2
```

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: are you sure you have a `submit` element submitting to the form? you should really just do: `if($_POST){ }` which will give you the same outcome. MySQL should be in capitals too. Is there a mysql_error at all? Change `$res1=mysql_query($des);` to `$res1 = mysql_query OR die(mysql_error());`

Comment: That's fine. Your form has been submitted. Is there any error you got?

Comment: One really important note: this code is highly insecure because you do not seem to be validating or escaping the POST data in any way. This is very vulnerable to SQL injection, meaning someone could erase or view your entire database. I know you're still working out the basics, but you MUST run this function on each value you are going to insert: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php before putting it into the query. Also, look into parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a few mistakes in your code just by regarding it... make sure you have all warning on so you could see them

1) Brackets after the if, or else only the assignation of the $des variable will be executed when the form is submitted

2) $_POST is an array.. you need the quotes $_POST['txtcompname']

finally make sure that the submit input has `name="submit"` ,although i think it's better to evaluate the submit by using `if !empty($_POST)`

good luck

Answer (score 4):

There are several potential problems here, but I'd need to see your whole script to give you a definitive answer.

Questions you should be asking - is $_POST['submit'] set? Print something to output inside the if to find out. Is your submit button value "Submit" rather than "submit" for example.

You should also try looking at mysql_error() to see if the DB is rejecting your query. Are your field names correct for example?

Lastly, $_POST[txtcompname] should be $_POST['txtcompname'] and your other $_POST vars also need quotes round the form field names. Depending on your version and configuration of PHP you might get away with this, but it's bad practice. Without the quotes PHP interprets txtcompname as a constant (as defined by define()). By default that may be set to the string txtcompname, so it might work, but you shouldn't rely on it.

Also, if this is a public facing site, you're setting yourself up for SQL injection problems since you've not escaped or otherwise sanitised your input. If your input has ' characters in it your query will break.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if Form got submitted
2. Debug the submitted Data (print)
3. **Validate // Sanitize the Data**
4. Build the Query Debug it (print)
5. Push the Query to the Database
6. Print error (if there is one)

If done so you have had seen that there is missing a space between `enquiry` and `(Companyname`

```
function debug($var, $label = '') {
    echo $label
        . '<pre>'
        . print_r($var, true)
        . '</pre>';
}

if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST)) {
    debug($_POST, '_POST');
    $_dbCompany = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcompname']);
    $_dbName        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtname']);
    $_dbPhone       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtphno']);
    $_dbEmail       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtemail']);
    $_dbAdress      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtaddress']);
    $_dbComments    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtcomments']);

    $_prepareSQL = "INSERT INTO 
        enquiry (Companyname,Name,Phno,Email,Address,Comments) 
        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')";
    $statement = sprintf($_prepareSQL, $_dbCompany, $_dbName, $_dbPhone, $_dbEmail, $_dbAdress, $_dbComments);
    debug($statement, 'SQL-Query');

    $result = mysql_query($statement) || trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[txtcompname] and all the other variables should be quoted. Try with $_POST['txtcompname']. Also, do var_dump($_POST) and check if you have all the values that you are reffering to.

Comment: Quotes has nothing to do with empty submit.